# How do I calculate the mean of all subsequent rows in pandas efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Given a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
date,score
2019-10-01,5
2019-10-02,4
2019-10-03,3
2019-10-04,6
```

How do I go about calculating the mean of `score` using subsequent/following rows, such that it looks/behaves like this:

```
date,score
2019-10-01,5,(5+4+3+6)/4
2019-10-02,4,(4+3+6)/3
2019-10-03,3,(3+6)/2
2019-10-04,6,6
```

This is super easy in SQL which is where I am trying to translate this from, where in SQL I can write:

`select avg(score) over(order by date) ...`

But I'm having trouble trying to figure this out in pandas.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try `expanding` on the reversed series

```
df['calc_mean'] = df.score[::-1].expanding(1).mean()

Out[228]:
         date  score  calc_mean
0  2019-10-01      5   4.500000
1  2019-10-02      4   4.333333
2  2019-10-03      3   4.500000
3  2019-10-04      6   6.000000
```

Comment: `expanding` is nice but I think can be kinda slow ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `cumsum` bottom-up and divide by the `arange`

```
df['cummean'] = df.score[::-1].cumsum()[::-1] / np.arange(len(df), 0, -1)
```

---

```
         date  score   cummean
0  2019-10-01      5  4.500000
1  2019-10-02      4  4.333333
2  2019-10-03      3  4.500000
3  2019-10-04      6  6.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

`cumsum` on reverse series:

```
df['cum_mean'] = (df[::-1].assign(c=1)
                    .agg({'score':'cumsum', 'c':'cumsum'})
                    .assign(cum_mean = lambda x: x['score']/x['c'])
                    ['cum_mean']
                 )
```

Output:

```
         date  score  cum_mean
0  2019-10-01      5  4.500000
1  2019-10-02      4  4.333333
2  2019-10-03      3  4.500000
3  2019-10-04      6  6.000000
```